# How to call BulkAll method in Elasticsearch NEST asynchronously in a Windows application

Tags: c#, asynchronous, elasticsearch, nest

Following the example here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/tree/5.x I can see method to use the BulkAll call synchronously.
How would i call this in an asynchronously? Is this possible? Can i use other method to emulate this functionality?

Appreciate the help,
Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't want to call it asynchronously; `BulkAll` is `IObservable<T>` based and internally, bulk requests are asynchronous, so the intention with an observable based helper is that you start it and wait for it to complete by blocking using `ManualResetEvent` or similar.

Comment: @RussCam So is there a way for me to show progress and cancel during this call. I am new to APM so bear with me, thanks!

Comment: You can show progress using an `onNext` action delegate of the `BulkAllObserver`, and you can cancel the operation using the `CancellationToken` passed to `client.BulkAll<T>(...)`

Comment: @RussCam I tried these steps. From a UI button click I start a progress bar, then call the bulkAll with a cancellation token and subscribe to it. In the onNext delegate i have progress increment, check for cacellation and call Cancel. But i am unable to cancel the progress since the waithandle is blocking the UI thread. What have i messed up here? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: I see, is this a Windows application, or a web app? For a windows app, you won't need to use a waithandle to wait. Instead, kick off the bulkall on a background thread and use onNext, onError and onCompleted delegates to determine what to show in the UI, using the UI thread.

Comment: @RussCam It is a Windows application, I will try that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  var bulkAllObservable = _client.BulkAll(list, b => b
                                    .Index(_indexName)
                                    // how long to wait between retries
                                    .BackOffTime("30s")
                                    // how many retries are attempted if a failure occurs
                                    .BackOffRetries(2)
                                    // refresh the index once the bulk operation completes
                                    .RefreshOnCompleted()
                                    // how many concurrent bulk requests to make
                                    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                                    // number of items per bulk request
                                    .Size(1000)
                                );

            Task.Run(() => bulkAllObservable.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), b => { })).RunSynchronously();
```